# content-package-maven-plugin no deploy support

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, aem

I have started using `content-package-maven-plugin` to build my package so that I can remove a lot of the meta data from my project.

My problem is that this plugin does not seem to support the `mvn:deploy` phase. I was previously using the `maven-assembly-plugin`, is there a way I could use the assembly plugin to `mvn:deploy` the output of the `content-package-maven-plugin` or is there another plugin that would provide me with this functionality?

TO BE CLEAR

**deploy** in this context refers to the **maven** lifecycle phase http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

I am **not** asking about **deploy**/install/upload to AEM.

Comment: After using maven for many years I have never heard of the plugin you're using and googling it doesn't seem to help much. Perhaps you should ask the developers?

Comment: I hadn't heard of it until this morning ;) Its Adobe AEM/CQ plugin http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html

Comment: I'm usually using the vault plugin:
<plugin>
 <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-vault-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.6</version>
 <extensions>true</extensions>
 <configuration>
  <verbose>true</verbose>
  <targetURL>http://${crx.host}:${crx.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
Not sure what the differences between these two are.

Comment: @Thomas yes I use that one also, I use it to upload packages to crx. I think the confusion comes from adobe's plugins 'deploying' to a remote crx. The vault plugin does not support `maven deploy` phase as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

`content-package-maven-plugin`  supports install which will perform the deployment of package in the crx. I guess by deploy you mean the same. Check http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool/vlt-mavenplugin.html#install

Comment: Yes it does, there is much confusion here because adobe use overlapping terminology with maven. I want to `mvn:deploy` my aem package.I will update my question